# querySelectorAll not removing class in else block

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to remove/add disable class on checkboxes when edit checkbox is changed, Although my code is working up to if block but when we uncheck the edit checkbox, however, the disable class is not reflecting in else block,
I have to attach disable class in querySelector all, as some checkboxes should work stand alone

Javascript code, on else block, disable class is not working

```js
// Javascript code, on else block, disable class is not working

let el = document.querySelector('.edit-checkbox');
el.addEventListener('change', function(){
  let ele = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox.disable');

  for(let i = 0; i< ele.length; i++){
    if(el.checked){
      ele[i].classList.remove('disable');
    } else{
      ele[i].classList.add('disable');
      ele[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox">
  Edit Checkboxes
</label>
</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain little more when your editcheckbox is checked all the checkbox should get checked and what all other conditions

Comment: when edit checkbox is checked, disable class should be removed, and when we uncheck the edit checkbox , disable class should get added

Comment: I mean, if you remove the `disable` class then `document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox.disable')` will not match any element the next time.

Comment: so basically the editCheckbox is select all kind of a feature isn't for the below checkboxes, when you click on it all the checkbox should gets selected and when you uncheck the editcheckbox all should be unchecked. am i correct

Comment: i have to  add disable class in  ```document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox.disable')``` because there may be another checkboxes which don't need to be disable

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS you are right

Comment: @ishfaq i have added the answer as you required kindly check and let me know anything to be updated

Answer (score 0):

Iusse is with the selector, once you remove `disable` class. `document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox.disable')` will not find elements.

Sol: use only `document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')` to select, but toggle based on value checked`[ele[i].checked]`.

```js
// Javascript code, on else block, disable class is not working

let el = document.querySelector('.edit-checkbox');
el.addEventListener('change', function(){
  let ele = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');

  for(let i = 0; i< ele.length; i++){
    if(el.checked){
      ele[i].classList.remove('disable');
      ele[i].checked = true;
      ele[i].disabled = false;
    } else{
      ele[i].classList.add('disable');
      ele[i].checked = false;
      ele[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
})

let el2 = document.querySelector('.edit-checkbox2');
el2.addEventListener('change', function(){
  let ele = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox2');

  for(let i = 0; i< ele.length; i++){
    if(ele[i].checked){
      ele[i].classList.add('disable');
      ele[i].checked = false;
    } else{
      ele[i].classList.remove('disable');
      ele[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.disable {
  outline: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox">
  Edit Checkboxes
</label>
</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>


<br/>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox2">
  Toggle
</label>
</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2 disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2 disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2 disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2 disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2 disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2"/>
```

Comment: I know this already, i-e why I am looking for a solution, I have to add disable class, please read the question once more

Comment: you have to use, disabled to disable the field. adding class will not make disabled. anyway check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem what i found is basically you need to have one more check, so you have 6 small checkbox which listen to one parent checkbox and by default one childbox should be disabled in the initial run and once you do the first run then from it should work normally.

So you need to have one check to know whether the class name disable exist.

I hope the below snippet will solve the issue.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.edit-checkbox');
el.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let ele = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');

  for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (el.checked && ele[i].classList.contains('disable')) {
      ele[i].classList.remove('disable');
      ele[i].checked = true
    } else {
      ele[i].classList.add('disable');
      ele[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox">
  Edit Checkboxes
</label>
</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
```

Comment: the problem is when we uncheck the edit button the last element will get also disable class, which we don't need,

Comment: still i am getting confusion on the question, when you load the first time 5 checkbox should be checked and one should be unchecked and when you click on main checkbox what should happen

Comment: I will try to make it more clear, checkboxes with disable class, have to have add remove class, on edit button click only

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is , add another class with disable class only

```
// Javascript code, on else block, disable class is not working
 let addClassToDisabled = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox.disable');
  for(let i = 0; i < addClassToDisabled.length; i++){
      addClassToDisabled[i].classList.add('toggle-edit');
  }
let el = document.querySelector('.edit-checkbox');
el.addEventListener('change', function(){
  let ele = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox.toggle-edit');

  for(let i = 0; i< ele.length; i++){
    if(el.checked){
      ele[i].classList.remove('disable');
    } else{
      ele[i].classList.add('disable');
      ele[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox">
  Edit Checkboxes
</label>
</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox disable"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
```